# Why a stackview disappear after 3 seconds when a keyboard is shown Swift 4?

Tags: ios, keyboard, swift4

At the bottom of the screen,I have a `stackView` with a `TextView` inside it.TextView will `becomeFirstResponder()` in `viewDidLoad()`.What I want is,the keyboard is shown below the stackView as I mention.

Here is my code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() //here will hide the keyboard

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

        if let window = self.view.window?.frame {
            // We're not just minusing the kb height from the view height because
            // the view could already have been resized for the keyboard before
            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                    y: self.view.frame.origin.y,
                                    width: self.view.frame.width,
                                    height: window.origin.y + window.height - keyboardSize.height)
            }

        }
    }

 @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

            let viewHeight = self.view.frame.height
            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                     y: self.view.frame.origin.y,
                                     width: self.view.frame.width,
                                     height: viewHeight + keyboardSize.height)
        }
    }
```

After apply the code above,the Keyboard is shown.The `stackView` I mention is above the keyboard for 3 seconds.Then the `stackView` at the bottom disappear.Even when I hide the keyboard,the `stackView` also never shown out.

I totally have no idea what is happening.Somebody please kindly explain whats going wrong with my code here

Comment: how do you lay out the view?

Comment: the stackView at the bottom,I set the constraints of leading,trailing and bottom to 0 in order to make it stick at the bottom @MilanNosáľ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()            
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)    
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {        
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

        self.viewBotCon.constant = -1 * keyboardSize.height

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }        
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

      self.viewBotCon.constant = 0

      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: `ViewBotCon` is refer to what ya??

Comment: bottom constraint of the view you want to move up/down drag it as IBOutlet'

Answer (score 0):

Try to use autolayout as much as possible. It's better to treat frame and bounds property as readonly.

The best way to do it actually

1. setup constraint from bottom of stack view to safe area, and expose it to you code via IBOutlet.
2. I advice you to subscribe for UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame - it then you will able to react on changes in keyboard as well.
3. Use window coordinate space to calculate all intersections with keyboard: `let stackViewFrame = stackView.convert(stackView.bounds, to: nil)`
4. Calculate intersection between keyboard and you stackview: `let intersection = keyboardFrame.intersection(stackViewFrame)`
5. Adjust constant of your  constraint to intersection + offset: `constraint.constant = intersection.size.height + offset`
6. Get animation time from notification  `let duration = notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey].floatValue`
7. and update layout with animation:   `UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {self.view.layoutIfNeeded() }`

PS: You subscribing for notifications in viewDidLoad and never unsubscribing from them. It means that if you have any other subsequent Scenes your viewcontroller will react on them as well, consuming performance and probably causing defects. It's better practice to subscribe for keyboard notifications in `viewWillAppear` and unsubscribe in `viewDidDisappear`.

PSS: And it will be good for your skills to use subscription with blocks rather then selectors.